# How do I reverse serial downvoting on my posts?

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes, serial-voting

I must have caused someone to be angry at me, because these two reputation changes happened within a few seconds:
[image: downvoting]

These two posts are the ones with the most votes, so they are on top of the lists displayed on the summary of my profile - which suggests that the serial downvoter is pretty careless in hiding his tracks ;)

Still, I've got very little reputation and these 4 points may seem little, but they mean much to me - so how can I reverse the serial downvoting?

Comment: Reversals are automatic, overnight. Two votes is probably too low to trip it though and might not be anything untoward.

Comment: You cannot do this yourself. Serial voting reversal is entirely automated, a script runs once per day around 3am UTC. That said, 2 downvotes are most likely *not* going to be reverted.

Comment: but 4 points is so much :(

Comment: Can you add links to your downvoted posts in your question please?

Comment: @Cupcake: It's easy enough to find them in the OP profile. Not sure what'd it would add, but here they are: [What's wrong with this regex: /(?:(?:^|\s)hide\_(\[^\s\]+))+/?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21858583), [Simple foreach search within multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24724782)

Comment: @Jonan: in the long run, 4 points is trump change. Don't worry about it, move on. Even now it is no more than 0.5% of your total. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know, but still I don't like people downvoting for such reasons

Comment: @Jonan: Sure, but in this case, you cannot do anything about it. With all such things where the actual impact on your life is minimal, you move on.

Comment: I briefly reviewed your activity and, other than seeing that you're pretty active generally, I didn't see anything that would be a red flag for creating ill will.

Comment: As others have said, 4 rep isn't significant (although it can *feel* significant when your rep is low)... However, what I think IS significant is when someone serial downvotes ANSWERS and that marks one's answers as "poor", when they are in fact valid and potentially useful to site users. This is my biggest concern over serial downvoting *that isn't auto-detected*.

Answer (score 5):

Serial downvoting is automatically reversed by the Stack Exchange system on a daily basis.

Some instances of downvoting may not be reversed. In these cases, there is not much you can do other than to just move on, and ask/answer more questions.

Comment: Within 24 hours, never more. The reversal script runs around 03:00 UTC.